# How to fix Blocking screen with content On my quick app pages?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

On my quick app pages, some
content may be blocked by the app menu. For example, the sign-in entry is blocked by the app menu in the following figure.

[image]

Although the menu is configured to be movable, users do not know that they can move it.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solutions are provided to solve your problem:

- Separating the menu from any content displayed
- Hiding the menu
- Adding a message indicating that the menu is movable

For Detail,pls kindly refer this link : [**What if some content is blocked by the app menu?**](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201345829066620139?fid=0101246461018590361)

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the menu from any content displayed by changing the value of titleBar to true in the manifest.json file.

```
e.g.
"display": {
"fullScreen": false,
"titleBar": "true",
"menu": false,
"menuBarData": {
"draggable": true
},
```

There is a good example with other solutions. Please check [link](https://medium.com/huawei-developers/quick-app-app-content-blocked-by-menu-teach-you-one-way-to-solve-it-acf7dd5a4562)